# Unable to connect bitbucket source repository from azure

Tags: azure, bitbucket, continuous-deployment

I am trying to connect bitbucket source repository from azure for continuous integration but I am getting error like "Invalid client_id
This integration is misconfigured. Contact the vendor for assistance" in authorization step.is there any idea what's happening? Please help me!! Thanks

Comment: I think this must be a problem on azure's or bitbucket's end. Mine also started doing it about an 1 or 2 ago.

Comment: Same here. I reported it to Microsoft via the "Feedback" tool in the Portal since there doesn't seem to be any way to report a bug specifically. My guess is the problem is exactly what the error message says; Azure's client_id for Bitbucket integration is no longer valid (could happen for any number of reasons). What IS surprising is that it would go so long without being fixed (or noticed, even).

Comment: Something is up, same time this started happening my environment variables stopped applying during builds.

Comment: Talking with someone at azure about this ATM. Will update when I know more.

Comment: Azure wants me to raise a technical support ticket, which I don't have a subscription for and which errors when I try to buy one. So I'm still stuck.

Comment: I am having the same problem!

Comment: Same problem for we as well...

Comment: me too - it worked when i last tried about 3 weeks to a month ago

Comment: Issue is being investigated. Please track https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dbfc01de-95c5-42d7-9777-551447dd8856/can-not-connect-azure-web-app-to-bitbucket-for-deployment-source?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview for latest.

Comment: I raised a ticket with Bitbucket and they got hold of Azure. They say that Azure made some changes and now need to update configurations on their end. For anybody who has a technical azure support subscription, my ticket reference with Atlassian was 
BBS-33289. They sending me an email now with someone who can apparently help but must admit to not being overly optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

The issue should now be resolved. It was caused by a bad update on the Azure side which caused unwanted side effect.

**Important**: note that at this point, the fix is only in the new portal (portal.azure.com). Please do not use manage.windowsazure.com to set up Bitbucket.

Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your useful answer.